# Install4j uninstall directory

Tags: installation, uninstallation, install4j

I'm building setup in install4j but some files I unziped in installation directory and some files in data directory not uninstall.

For examle:
C:\Program Files\MyApp - it's directory where set up my app and in this directory I install postgresql (unzip from zip file) C:\Program Files\MyApp\postgresql
C:\MyData\Myapp - data directory (f.e. data of PostgreSQL need install not in system directory)

For save path of my app I create windows registery and put value there.

I tried removing the MyApp in two ways:

1) In 'Run script' action I get path of my data from register (File dataDir = new File(pathToDataDir)) and later try uninstall by dataDir.delete() and also try run script 'rmdir "pathToDataDir'. This option does not work due of permissions.

2) In this way I try to register path of my register in install4j by two methods (context.installDirectory and context.registerUninstallFile()) and later install4j (in my opinion) should be install my directories. In file /.install4j/files.log I find my directories, but install4j not uninstalled directories.

What problem can there be in this case?

Sorry for my English =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "Install content of a ZIP file" action to extract the ZIP file in such a way that the extracted files will be removed by the installer.

Alternatively, a "Delete files and directories" action in the uninstaller will remove selected files or directories.

Comment: "Install content of a ZIP file" not option for me, because later I in "Run script" action install postgresql (create cluster and another options..)
I try to uninstall with "Delete files and directories" and it not working for me..

Comment: Why is the "Delete files and directories" action not working for you?

Comment: This action not deleted file. How to check why not deleted file?

Comment: Execute the uninstaller with `-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=/path/to/logfile.txt` and check the log.

Comment: Oh..Just need check checkbox "Recursive"...Thanks you so much